Why does my Google Sheets query simplificaiton result in an error?
I have a Google sheet question. I use a formula to sum all values of a column that contains keywords in an other column. I use this formula :
=QUERY(Data!A1:I; "SELECT SUM(G) WHERE (LOWER(B) CONTAINS 'jumbo' OR LOWER(B) CONTAINS 'lidl' OR LOWER(B) CONTAINS 'albert' OR LOWER(B) CONTAINS 'picnic') AND F = 'Af' LABEL SUM(G)''"; 1)

I tried to simplify the formula to this :
=QUERY(Data!A:I, "SELECT SUM(G) WHERE LOWER(B) MATCHES 'jumbo|lidl|albert|picnic'", 1)

But it gives an error. Is the first formula still the one to go or are there other options?

We need to see the error in order to help you.

Your second formula gives an error because the MATCHES operator in Google Sheets is case-sensitive and requires the use of regular expressions. To fix it you can modify the query to include (?i) to make the regular expression case-insensitive. Additionally, you need to keep the F = 'Af' condition from your first query if it’s still required.
Here 2 simplified versions of your formula using MATCHES:
=QUERY(Data!A:I, "SELECT SUM(G) WHERE LOWER(B) MATCHES '(?i)jumbo|lidl|albert|picnic' AND F = 'Af'", 1)

=QUERY(Data!A:I, "SELECT SUM(G) WHERE LOWER(B) MATCHES '.*(jumbo|lidl|albert|picnic).*' AND F = 'Af'", 1)

This should work by matching the keywords in column B and summing the corresponding values in column G where column F equals "Af".

Thanks for giving me the correct direction. This one worked out for me :
=QUERY(Data!A:I; "SELECT SUM(G) WHERE LOWER(B) MATCHES '.(jumbo|lidl|albert|picnic).' AND F = 'Af' LABEL SUM(G) ''"; 1)

The regex engine used in the QUERY function assumes that the start and end of line anchors are present (i.e. matches 'foo' is the same as matches '^foo$'). Which means that the equivalent of contains 'foo' is matches '.*foo.*' not matches 'foo'.
=QUERY(Data!A:I, "SELECT SUM(G) WHERE LOWER(B) MATCHES '.*(jumbo|lidl|albert|picnic).*'", 1)

You could also do this using the SUMPRODUCT function.
=SUMPRODUCT(Data!G:G,REGEXMATCH(Data!B:B,"(?i)jumbo|lidl|albert|picnic"))


If range K2:K10 is housing your keywords, another alternative is;
=QUERY(A2:I,"Select Sum(G) Where Lower(B) Matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, K2:K10) & "' Label Sum(G) ''")

And/Or;
=QUERY(A2:I,"Select Sum(G) Where F= 'Af' And Lower(B) Matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, K2:K10) & "' Label Sum(G) ''")

